# Redirecting a login.html or registration.html form that is connected to a database using php to the main page written in html

Tags: php, html, mysql

How do I redirect users after they have either registered or login from either login page or register page to the main page

I tried using the header func(location:) but when I try it the page says the url cannot be found 404 error

Comment: Without knowing your code all we could suggest is to use `header("Location: mainpage.html");`

Comment: What's the path/location? Where are the files? Same/different folders? Can you show the PHP part?

Answer (score 0):

I redirect users by echoing a script

```
echo " <script> window.location='index.php';</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting 'url cannot be found 404 error', there might be an error in your code. If your home page url is `home.php`, you can use the header function as `header("Location:home.php");`